# What's wrong with my Python program that is supposed to convert from binary to decimal?

Tags: python, binary, decimal

We're supposed to write a "simple" program that converts from binary string. It's also supposed to return 0 when given an empty string. I apologize in advance to my lack of knowledge. I'm completely new to this.

Here's my attempt:

```
def b(binaryString):
   if binaryString[0] !=0 or binaryString[1] !=1:
       return 0
   else:
       x = int(binaryString[1])
       a = (len(binaryString)) - 1
       return x * 2**a + b(binaryString[1:])
```

Sample Input: b('1101')

Expected Output: 13

Actual Output: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you give us some sample inputs, the actual output, and the expected output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than replying in comments.

Comment: *It's also supposed to return 0 when given an empty string.* Ugh, what an ugly requirement.

Comment: Do you need it to be recursive as well?  Or what that just something you were experimenting with?

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be recursive. Sorry, should've mentioned that. Also we are to assume that we won't be given bad data as an input.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant solution... however, here are my two cents

```
def b(binaryString):
 if len(binaryString):
    try:
        return sum([int(num)*2**(idx) for idx,num in enumerate(reversed(binaryString))])
    except ValueError:
        return "Your input might be incorrect"
 else:
    return "0"



print(b("111")) #returns 7
print(b(""))    #returns 0
print (b("11111101111")) #returns 2031
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm in the early weeks of a 101 course, so your solution is too "difficult." We've mostly been using recursive functions, find, rfind, len,  and indexes so far so I was hoping to somehow be able to solve the problem somehow with those.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: @Kevin Brown, As you can see from the numbers next to my avatar I am a complete newbie to stackoverflow. Thanks for the tips, I will keep these in mind. Cheers :) !

Answer (score 1):

```
def b(binaryString):
    if len(binaryString) == 0: return 0
    rest, lsb = binaryString[:-1], binaryString[-1]
    lsb = 1 if lsb == '1' else 0      # Alternatively, lsb = int(lsb)
    return (b(rest) << 1) + lsb       # Alternatively, return b(rest) * 2 + lsb
```

Where:

```
print b('1101')      # 13
print b('')          # 0
print b('11111111')  # 255
print b('10')        # 2
print b('01')        # 1
```

The code splits the input string into two variables `rest` and `lsb`.

`rest` contains the input string, up to but excluding the last bit.

`lsb` contains the least significant bit (last bit in string).  It's converted to an `int` in the following line.

The return value of the function is `b(rest)` shifted up 1 bit (= *2) plus the integer value of lsb.

Worth noting is that you could "cheat" with something as simple as:

```
def b(binaryString):
    return int('0' + binaryString, base=2)
```